# http.ServeFile and http.ServeContent cannot handle multiple clients

Tags: go, stream

**Scenario** 
I created a simple video streamer using golang. At First, I used `http.ServeContent` to serve my videos. It was working until I *simultaneously* connected 4 tabs to my server but the first two only works and the rest aren't loading at all. I can navigate to the menu while streaming the two videos but I can't stream on the rest. I also tried it using multiple devices. Only two connections can stream.

So, I changed `http.ServeContent` to `http.ServeFile` but its still the same but when I used `io.Pipes`, It served every request but the problem is that It can't seek.

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func serveVideo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    title := vars["title"]
    ep := vars["ep"]
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "video/" + title + "/" ep + ".mp4")
}

func main() {
     const port string = "8080"
    // Create mux router
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/video/{title}/{ep}", serveVideo)
    // let mux handle
    http.Handle("/", r)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

I wish you could help. Thank you.

Comment: It's possible there are issues at the server config level, limiting active connections. just fyi, I don't expect the Go code would do this so I'd check your apache config or something along those lines.

Comment: I don't have anything like _apache_ or _nginx_ running. I'm running On Windows 10 64 bit. Any Ideas?

Comment: Open IIS to find similar settings

Comment: Where in the code are the pending requests are blocked?

Comment: @JimB it was being blocked inside the `http.ServeFile`

Comment: Can you get a stack trace to see exactly where it's blocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your code is fine. All major browsers will normally limit the number of parallel active connections to a host.

As a simple test, try streaming multiple times with something like `curl` to confirm there is actually a problem with your code. Alternatively, try running different browsers simultaneously (e.g. 2 tabs in Chrome, 2 tabs in Firefox etc)

Comment: I tried 2 tabs on Chrome first, its working fine as expected, but It didn't on Firefox (While Chome is open). While those are open, I tried curl but I didn't receive anything.

Comment: Your code works fine on my system. I can have 4 concurrent connections all serving content with no problems. As I said, your code is fine. There is obviously an environment/configuration issue somewhere on your system. Why don't you trying running on a cheap VPS from someone like Digital Ocean / Vultr?